# No conversion from text to string - ajax call fails

Tags: ajax, jquery

I upgraded my page from using jquery 1.4.4 to jquery 1.9.1 and suddenly my ajax calls stopped working. If i revert to jquery 1.4.4 it works again. I am getting below error.

> No conversion from text to string

Below is my code

```
 $.ajax({ url: "/Reporting/RunQuery",
          type: "Post",
          data: { prm_Query: qrytxt }, dataType: "string",
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, error) {
                debugger;
                alert("The following error occured while adding data: " + error);
           },
           success: function (data) {
               debugger;
               $('#divQuerytextarea').html('').append(data);
            }
           });
```

My call to /Reporting/RunQuery succeeds and it has valid return string in the RunQuery method. Then it falls into error: of ajax call with 'No conversion from text to string' error.

Not finding much in google for this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a "string" datatype in jQuery ajax, use "text" instead.

Comment: did you try without dataType "string", i don't think it's necessary

Comment: Thank you so much guys.. it works with dataType: "text" or even without it. What is recommended, having as "text" or not having dataType ?

Comment: The default is an "intelligent guess" so it will figure it out in most cases. You don't really need it unless you require it in a certain format (like json or xml).

Comment: If you expect text and your code will fail if it's interpreted as, for example, json, or xml, then yes. Normally it is just left off.

Comment: Another note, you don't need `.html('').append(data)` just do `.html(data)`.

Comment: Thank you Kevin.. If you or Dany Y can put this as an answer, i will accept it. Thank you all again

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Kevin. I was having the same problem just because I've put :

dataType: JSON

instead of :

dataType: "json"

after what everything worked fine.

Be aware that this "dataType" property commes from the HTTP head where there is the MIME type wich is the type of the resource called by the HTTP request. So there is no "string" type. You should use "text" instead (if you want a string, of course).